# Raspbian - MongoDB and MongoDB nodejs driver on different versions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspbian

I migrated my nodejs project from Ubuntu 64bit to Raspbian. I have an issue with mongodb driver.

My mongodb database is on version `db version v2.4.14`. Of course `npm install` installed the newest driver. Which leads to this error message:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: Server at localhost:27017 reports maximum wire version 0, but this version of the Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6)
```

I have tried downgrading nodejs driver to several older versions (oldest I tried was 5 years ago) but with no affect.

What else could I try?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the current MongoDB drivers do not support server 2.4.

I suggest updating the server to at least 2.6, if this is not possible you'll have to use an old driver that supports 2.4.

Server compatibility tables should exist in driver documentation, see [Ruby ones](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/reference/driver-compatibility/#mongodb-compatibility) for example.